# How To Show Jasper Report in Web Page Without Embedding Java Applet Along With Exporting Options of Several File Formats [ pdf , xls etc ]

Tags: jasper-reports, html, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf

I am developing an web application where i need to show a report to users. I am using jasper report for reporting. Now what i want to do is to show the jasper report in my web page along with option to export report in pdf/excel file format according to user preference. I don't want to embed java applet on my web page to show report. I have searched over internet and found sample of showing report in browser pdf reader. It solves my purpose of showing report in web page without using applet but by this i can only export report in pdf format. But i need to give user option of exporting in excel format too. So my question is what way i can achieve my goal as i mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found solution of my question. First, I exported jasper report in a html file & then showed the html file in my web page within a iframe which meet my purpose of showing report within web page. And exporting report is done by several exporter class like JRXlsExporter, JRPdfExporter etc. of jasper report.